# Responsive navbar toggle doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navbar

I'd like to ask you for help. I want to make responsive navbar similar to Bootstrap's navbar but it doesn't work as I expected.

Here is demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOodMg

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // toggle
  $("#navbar-btn").click(function() {
    $("#navbar-nav").toggle(2000);
  });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: Previous issue was fixed but there is responsive issue. If you click button for expand links then click again to hide and resize screen links don't appear. So what should I do?

Comment: your `jquery` has error

Comment: Yes, fixed this issue but generally navbar doesn't work as Bootstrap's. There is probably issue with responsive toggle.

Comment: its working fine after removing `ms` from that `jquery` code

Answer (score 1):

remove ms

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // toggle
  $("#navbar-btn").click(function() {
  $("#navbar-nav").toggle(2000);
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVwdzW

Comment: Yes, fixed this issue but generally navbar doesn't work as Bootstrap's. There is probably issue with responsive toggle.

Comment: make your time value `500`

Comment: There is responsive issue. If you click button for expand links then click again to hide and resize screen links don't appear. So what should I do? Any suggestions? Hmm?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not put `ms` behind your time value.

```
$("#navbar-nav").toggle(2000);
```

Comment: Yes, fixed this issue but generally navbar doesn't work as Bootstrap's. There is probably issue with responsive toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ms` from `2000ms` from your `jquery` code